# updating to separate DIVs via ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have 2 elements on my page that I am trying to reload via ajax - however I can only ever seem to update one. Below is my code,

```
$('#messages_send').live('click', function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: base_url + 'ajax/send_message',
        data: {
            username: $('#messages_username').val(),
            message: $('#messages_message').val(),
            saveid: $('#messages_savedid').val(),
        },
        success: function(data) {
            sending_message();

            var x = jQuery.parseJSON(data);

            if(x) {
                if(x.gp_id==80)
                {
                        $('#spn_ucredit').load(base_url + 'ajax/userdata/credits');
                        $('#overlay_credits').load(base_url + 'ajax/userdata/credits');
                }
            }
            //$('#spn_ucredit').html($('#ncd_id').val());
            //tmp_cost = $('#spn_ucredit').html()-$('#ncd_id').val();
            //$('#ncd_id').val($('#ncd_id').val()-tmp_cost);
            //alert(data);
            setTimeout(message_sent, 2000);
            setTimeout(remove_modal_box, 3000);
            setTimeout(message_revert, 3500);
            $("#saved_messages").load(base_url + 'messages #saved_messages > form');
           $("#messages_content").load(base_url + 'messages #messages_content > form');
        }
    });

    return false;
});
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: try use instead load - > $.get(url, data, function(result){$("#element").html(result) })

Comment: Some tips: Replace "live" with "on", and "return false" with "e.preventDefault" (after e has been declared in the function). Are you getting any errors in the console?

Comment: @Johan: We do not know what version OP has. `on` can only be used since version 1.7.2. If OP is using a version below 1.7 but over 1.4.2 then `delegate` should be used instead of `live` for dynamic bindings and `bind` to attach events to static elements.

Comment: sico, why the setTimeouts - just for visual effect or do they anticipate completion of the load requests?

Comment: The set timeouts are just for visual effect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sico,

There's a number of things you can do to debug/improve the code, chief amongst which is to reduce the number of HTTP requests. With `$.get()` instead of `.load()`, it should be possible to use the HTTP responses twice each.

Something like this :

```
$(document).on('click', '#messages_send', function() {
    sending_message();
    $.ajax({
        url: base_url + 'ajax/send_message',
        data: {
            username: $('#messages_username').val(),
            message: $('#messages_message').val(),
            saveid: $('#messages_savedid').val(),
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            var creditsPromise, messagesPromise;//vars that allow .when() later.
            if(data.gp_id == 80) {
                creditsPromise = $.get(base_url + 'ajax/userdata/credits', function(data) {
                    $('spn_ucredit').html(data);
                    $('#overlay_credits').html(data);
                });
            }
            else {
                creditsPromise = (new $.Deferred()).resolve().promise();
            }
            messagesPromise = $.get(base_url + 'messages', function(data) {
                var $data = $(data);
                $("#saved_messages").empty().append($data.find('#saved_messages > form'));
                $("#messages_content").empty().append($data.find('#messages_content > form'));
            });

            $.when(creditsPromise, messagesPromise).done(function() {//fires when both $.get()s have successfully responded
                message_sent();
                setTimeout(remove_modal_box, 1000);
                setTimeout(message_revert, 1500);
            });
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

This reduces the number of HTTP requests from five to three.

You could further reduce the number of HTTP requests to one, though you would need to write a server-side script to perform everything currently performed by `...ajax/send_message`, `...ajax/userdata/credits` and `...messages`, and json-encode a composite response.

The client-side code could then simplify to something like this:

```
$(document).on('click', '#messages_send', function() {
    sending_message();
    $.ajax({
        url: base_url + 'ajax/send_message',
        data: $("#messages form").serialize(),//assumed
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            if(data.gp_id == 80) {
                $('#spn_ucredit').html(data.credits);
                $('#overlay_credits').html(data.credits);
            }
            $("#saved_messages").html(data.saved_messages);
            $("#messages_content").html(data.messages_content);
            message_sent();
            setTimeout(remove_modal_box, 1000);
            setTimeout(message_revert, 1500);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```